# Logging in Node JS gear in OpenShift stopped

Tags: node.js, logging, openshift

I deleted my ~/nodejs/logs/node.log file in OpenShift server because it's too big. Now even if I restart my gear, it doesn't log to file anymore. I tried creating a new file node.log and chmod 777 node.log but still nothing. Any idea?

Before it was working (delete log file, restart server, log file is created again), now I think it's broken. I can replicate it in several OpenShift nodejs gears.

Additional info: I use log4js v0.6.x, OpenShift nodejs gear 0.10

Comment: I'm having the exact same experience... Trying to figure out why... OpenShift must have made some change on logging recently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift gears have changed logging to point to a new standard location, see this blog post for details: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/new-features-for-april-2014

Comment: To really answer this question, the new location of logs is in ~/app-root/logs or in $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR

Comment: The blog post mentions $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR as the location. In my standard Node cartridge 12 Aug 2015, that variable is unassigned and the directory ~/app-root/logs does not exist.

Comment: sorry link is 404 :(